# OSX UI testing with XCUIApplication and covered windows

Tags: macos, xcode-ui-testing

The application which I am testing has two windows and if the one I wish to control is covered the by the second window, XCUIApplication will fail complaining  that it can not find the buttons it was programmed to click. What is the best way to handle this? Is there a way to bring a window to front and in focus using the XCUIApplication API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To focus a specific window before clicking something inside it, do the following.

`[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init].windows[@"Window"] click];`